# Find the area of $A = \{ \langle x,y\rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mathrel| (x+y)^4<a x^2 y,\ x>0 \}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I can't really think of how to set the limits

Comment: Yeah sorry I typed up the question incorrectly there was actually supposed to be $(x+y)^4$

Comment: @shimee is the integrand $1$? If so, you can just rephrase this as a single integral.

Comment: @oldrinb yes. All I want to do is find the area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways to find the area

1. use wolframalpha,you can see the picture at once.
2. let $x=rcos(\theta), y=rsin(\theta)$, then you get $r \le \dfrac{a*cos^2(\theta)sin(\theta)}{(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta))^4}$

since $x>0 \to -\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$,I think you can go further this way.

Edit:$ay>0$, if $a>0 \to y>0 \to 0< \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

the shape is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eank77u36ra)

EDIT: I add the process also for reference:

$S=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^ {\frac{\pi}{2}} r^2 (\theta)d \theta$  and

$ \int r^2 (\theta)d \theta=\int \left[\dfrac{a*cos^2(\theta)sin(\theta)}{(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta))^4} \right]^2 d \theta=a^2*\dfrac{-280 sin(\theta)-210 sin(3\theta)+14 sin(5\theta)-385 cos(\theta)+147 cos(3 \theta)+105 cos(5 \theta)+13 cos(7 \theta)}{6720 (sin(\theta)+cos(\theta))^7}+C$

$S=a^2*\dfrac{-280+210+14-(-385+147+105+13 )}{2*6720}=\dfrac{a^2}{210}$

Comment: I figured this much. So am I supposed to integrate $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^K r dr d \theta $ where $r <K(\theta)$ is the expression above? I'm getting infinity this way

Comment: I think your integration formula is not correct,it should be $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^K f(r,\theta)r dr d \theta$,be care that $K$ is max of $r$

Comment: what does your $f(r,\theta )$ stand for? remember, I'm only trying to find the area

Comment: f is the formula above which you may say $K(\theta)$ before. BTW, $\theta$'s range is small that I edit it.

Comment: sorry I am wrong for the area formula, it should be:$S=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} r^2(\theta) d \theta$

Comment: the final answer is $\dfrac{23a^2}{840}$

Comment: again a mistake, $\dfrac{a^2}{210}$ is right one.

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize the equation such as
$$x=x(t)$$
$$y=t*x(t)$$
and by replacing to the original equation
$$\big(x(t)+t\,x(t)\big)^4=a\,x(t)^2\,t\,x(t)\Rightarrow x(t)^4(1+t)^4=a\,t\,x(t)^3\Rightarrow x(t)=\frac{a\,t}{(1+t)^4}$$
The limits are $0$ and $\infty$. By Greens therom the area enclosed by the parametric curve is given by
$$A=\frac 12\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(x\,y'-y\,x'\bigg)dt=\frac 12\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(x\,(t\,x)'-t\,x\,x'\bigg)dt=\frac 12\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(x\,(x+t\,x')-t\,x\,x'\bigg)dt$$
$$A=\frac 12\int_0^{\infty}x^2dt=\frac 12\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{a\,t}{(1+t)^4}\bigg)^2dt$$
This is an improper integral and
$$A=\lim_{b \to \infty}\frac 12\int_0^b\bigg(\frac{a\,t}{(1+t)^4}\bigg)^2dt=\frac 12\lim_{b \to \infty}\bigg(-a^2\frac{1+7b+21b^2}{105(1+b)^7}+\frac{a^2}{105}\bigg)=\frac{a^2}{210}$$

Comment: why parametrize this way? is there a rule? how did you get the limits?

Comment: It is not a rule but it makes things very easy as you can see. The limits are determined as the values of t by making $x(t)=0$ and $y(t)=0$, it is clear that both values are zero when t is zero and when t goes to infinity.